# Move ProjectServer 2007 Workspace to SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, 2007, project-server, move

I have a MOSS 2007 Farm running ProjectServer 2007. In parallel I have a SharePoint 2010 Foundation Farm. Now I am planning to shutdown the old MOSS 2007.
Is there a way to export/move the ProjectServer 2007 Workspaces to a SharePoint 2010 Site Collection or Web Application with **no** Project Server 2010 installed?

There must be only the content available, browsable and search-/findable no more links to project plans or MS Project.

Answer (score 0):

In Project Server 2007 you have total 5 Databases as below.

- Project_Archive
- Project_Draft
- Project_Publish
- Project_Reporting
- WSS_Content

All your Project related information like the task, timesheet etc. are stored in first 4 Project databases and you Project Server Workspaces are stored in 5th Database i.e. WSS_Content. Its normal SharePoint Content database and can be migrated or upgraded as per SharePoint supportability.